# ld returned 1 exit status (саблайм)

Tags: c

Выводится ошибка, данная в в заголовке. Нашла код, переписала своими руками, но все равно выдает ошибку.

А также правильно поняла, что должно будет выводиться окно, где вписать свой символ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ();
{
  char ch;
  ch = getchar();
  putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: Интересно, как дело дошло до линковки...
Разве не было сообщения **error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token**

Comment: Было в онлайн компиляторе, так и не поняла, к сожалению, в чем суть ошибки

Comment: **не поняла, в чем суть ошибки** - боюсь, что этого никто не поймёт. Если убрать точку с запятой и скопилировать с помощью обычного *gcc*, то всё собирается нормально и программа работает. А использовать Sublim обязательно?

Comment: Хотелось бы использовать только его :(

Comment: @Elvis, поставь все библиотеки и пакеты, необходимые для сборки. Вполне вероятно, что линкер банально не знает, что дальше делать с объектником, так как инфраструктура сборки не стоит или криво установлены пакеты. И да, сообщения об ошибке тут нигде не видать. Приведи весь текст вывода.

Comment: Я раньше никогда не пользовался *Sublim*, так что могу и ошибиться, но ведь это просто - ТЕКСТОВЫЙ РЕДАКТОР. Или это полноценная IDE? Ведь можно текст простой программы хоть в блокноте редактировать - это не принципиально.  А компиляцию и сборку текстовый редактор точно НЕ выполняет. Так что у Вас проблема вот с этим самым окружением, которое и делает компиляцию и сборку.  Вы  хотя бы скажите ОС и компилятор, на котором работаете...

Comment: @Sergey, ну компилятор старый.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в конец функции

```
return 0;
```

Во-первых, если я ничего не путаю, его без последствий можно опускать только в си++, но не в си. Во-вторых, кажется, ты пользуешься каким-то древним компилятором.

http://codepad.org/tgsjaGYA

> �
>   Exited: ExitFailure 255

https://ideone.com/TaFHlO

> Успешно #stdin #stdout 0s 4308KB
>   �

Comment: `return 0;` подразумевается неявно так же как и в плюсах. **"reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0."**

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, компилятор на codepad'е с тобой явно не согласен.

Comment: Он не со мной не согласен, а со стандартом языка C11. Фактически он просто выводит [код возврата последней функции](http://codepad.org/Q4B1coao).

Answer (score 0):

Вашей крутой программе следует выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int ch;

    ch = getchar();

    putchar( ch );
}
```

Или

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int ch;

    ch = getchar();

    if ( ch != EOF ) putchar( ch );
}
```

Имейте в виду, что чтобы дождаться вывода программы, вам надо после введенного символа нажать клавишу Enter.

Comment: К сожалению, все та же ошибка

Comment: @Elvis А как выглядит полный текст сообщения об ошибке? И какой компилятор вы используете?

Comment: Мне как новичку посоветовали использовать компилятор в саблайме, а вот сама ошибка "C
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.1s]"

Comment: С каких пор EOF нельзя отправлять в putchar?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите точку с запятой после

```
int main();
```

!!!

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, нужно убрать точку с запятой после `main()`, во-вторых, по-хорошему `ch` должно иметь тип `int` (хотя в данном случае это непринципиально).

Можно и вовсе без нее :)

```
int main()
{
    putchar(getchar());
}
```

Comment: точку с запятой давно убрала, но, к сожалению, все та же ошибка

Comment: http://ideone.com/IF7Exx  Что-то у вас в локальной системе не то...

Comment: что же можно сделать?

Comment: Ну понимаете, удаленно ведь не понять, что у вас там делается... :(

Comment: А в-третьих, мимо.

Answer (score 0):

Нет кармы комментировать, так что отвечу.

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status не говорит какая ошибка была, а говорит о том, что ошибка была до этого. Посему, чтобы чем-то помочь, мы должны знать настоящую ошибку. Покопайтесь в логах или последних сообщениях, в поисках самой ошибки.

Comment: Что за бред? Каких логах??

Comment: Судя по твоим другим комментариям бред только у тебя в голове. Если уж подымаешь труп столетней давности, неплохо бы контекст восстановить. Почитай комментарии к вопросу и ответ автора: "Было в онлайн компиляторе, так и не поняла, к сожалению, в чем суть ошибки". Оказывается и сообщения и ошибки были и логи есть.